# What gui elements to be used?

Tags: python, wxpython, psycopg2, wxwidgets

I'm trying to create a journal entry interface, similar to those well known accounting softwares using wxpython for the gui and psycopg2 as backend. I tried doing it with a listctrl, but its use is not for that particular interaction. My question, is there a built-in widgets closely related to those elements?.

Comment: Which well known accounting software?

Comment: quickbooks, peachtree, and free accounting software, though free isn't that popular, but they have similar designs

Answer (score 1):

Download the wxPython Docs and Demos from http://wxpython.org/download.php. The demo allows you to "shop" for widgets easier since you get to see them in action and can view the code used to create them. I suggest checking out the UltimateListCtrl.